# Android Studio, Lists View con imagenes se hace lento

Tags: android-studio, listview

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el cual tengo una list view con imágenes, titulo y un numero. Pero cuando doy un scroll en esta list view, se pone lento a tal punto que la aplicación deja de funcionar. Tengo entendido que es por la imagen y su tamaño. Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo optimizar esto?
Les dejo por aquí mi adaptador:

```js
public class Adaptador_ListaRecetas extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    Context contexto;
    private static Integer[] id_receta;
    private static String[] Recetas;
    private static Integer[] Tiempo;
    private static String[] Video;
    String[] Imagen;


    public Adaptador_ListaRecetas(Context contexto, String[] recetas, Integer[] tiempo,Integer[] id_receta,String[] video,String[] imagen) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.id_receta=id_receta;
        this.Recetas = recetas;
        this.Tiempo = tiempo;
        this.Video= video;
        this.Imagen= imagen;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)contexto.getSystemService(contexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_listarecetas,null);

        Herramientas h=new Herramientas();

        TextView receta=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre); //Falta la imagen
        TextView tiempo=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);
        ImageView imagen=(ImageView)vista.findViewById(R.id.ivReceta);

        //AQUI ES DONDE COLOCO LA IMAGEN EN CADA ELEMENTO DE LA LISTA
        int imageResource=contexto.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+h.CortadorDireccionImagen(Imagen[i]),null,contexto.getPackageName());
        imagen.setImageResource(imageResource);

        receta.setText(h.getConvertidorNombreaIds(Recetas[i]));
        tiempo.setText(h.getConvertidorNombreaIds(h.CortadorDireccionImagen(Imagen[i])));

        vista.setTag(i);


        vista.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(Video[i].equals("")){
                    Intent visorRecetas = new Intent(contexto, Receta_SinVideo.class);
                    visorRecetas.putExtra("Tagid",id_receta[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
                    visorRecetas.putExtra("TagNombre",Recetas[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
                    contexto.startActivity(visorRecetas);

                }
                else{
                    Intent visorRecetas = new Intent(contexto, Receta_ConVideo.class);
                    visorRecetas.putExtra("Tagid",id_receta[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
                    visorRecetas.putExtra("TagNombre",Recetas[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
                    contexto.startActivity(visorRecetas);
                }

            }
        });

        return vista;
    }
    //Falta un get para obtener el id del la layout_receta

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Recetas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Para colocar la imagen uso "drawable" con el nombre de la imagen extraída de una base de datos local. Si tienen alguna otra pregunta, la respodere lo mas rápido que pueda.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, use una librería que vi en un video. Les dejo el enlace del video. https://youtu.be/cKUxiqNB5y0?list=LL4VzEJBjBZ3ToQ0fI3aosRQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes utilizar Recycler View.De este componente hay mucha informacion
te dejo un enlace con ejemplo
[Explicación de github](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrJ7FjSJcdc_BAAITxXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEyc3BrcXZlBGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDQUJBQ0tfMQRzZWMDc3I-/RV=2/RE=1556584018/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgooglesamples%2Fandroid-RecyclerView/RK=2/RS=16tiIf4vSuHaA5A4bJQHlYwdDhM-)

[otro ejemplo muy bueno](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrJ7FjSJcdc_BAAIzxXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEyNmpxcDhwBGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMyBHZ0aWQDQUJBQ0tfMQRzZWMDc3I-/RV=2/RE=1556584018/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fcodepath%2Fandroid_guides%2Fwiki%2FUsing-the-RecyclerView/RK=2/RS=ujAhANfojxC7Hb6Kb8wA_xRpG98-)